# How to reload the project in nodejs after modifiying

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, twig, nodemon

I am new in nodejs ,every time I create a project I have to restart the server after modifiying html files also when using twig,jade or ejs templates engines.
Any ideas on how make the changes show up on browser without restarting the server everytime.

this is server.js:

```js
var express=require('express');
var bodyParser=require('body-parser');
var path=require('path');
var twig=require('twig');

var app=express();
app.use(bodyParser.json());
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({extended:false}));
app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname,'public')));
app.set('view engine','twig');
app.set('twig options',{strict_variables:false});
app.set('views',path.join(__dirname,'views'));


 
app.get('/',function(req,res){
    res.render('index.twig',{message:'test'});
});

app.listen(3000,function(){
    console.log('Server started and listening on port 3000 ... ')
});
```

I use twig as view engine

views/index.twig :

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
    <title>Document</title>
</head>
<body>
    {{ message }}
</body>
</html>
```

I use nodemon also I tried with supervisor ,same nothing changed in both

Comment: Use `nodemon` to reload the server when a file changes.

Comment: Thanks , I am actually doing that but it's not helpful in dev-env what I am looking for is making the server load the changes dynamically without restarting it everytime

Comment: when u modify a file , you must then save the file which u modified. otherwise nodemon will not detect the file

Comment: Watching/reloading files in a production environment will adversely affect your performance - you shouldn't do it.

Answer (score 2):

To fix that you can use nodemon  like that

```
 nodemon -e .js,.twig app.js
```

You can also create nodemon.json in your root folder and add this config :

```
{
  "ext": "js,twig,mjs,json"
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Use **nodemon** npm module and reload your project when you have made changes.

Install nodemon globally

```
$ npm install -g nodemon
```

Install nodemon as a developement dependency

```
$ npm install --save-dev nodemon

$ cd [project path] // ex: myapp

$ nodemon [your node app] // nodemon ./server.js
```

Comment: I know that , But the isuue is that I am using Twig as templates engine and twig by default cache templates ,everytime I have to restart the server after editing to see the updates on the browser , so the solution is disable the cache :

twig.cache(false)